# xyz.froud.jvisa.JVisaException: in viRead(): Timeout expired before operation completed. (0xBFFF0015)

Tags: java

I am getting a timeout error with the following lines of code that are supposed to query the visa instrument with *IDN? SCPI command, get the result from the query, and display it to the terminal. It works for other instruments when I change the resource name but not for the current one embedded in the following code.

```
    package com.bluehalo.msda.cca.utils;
    
    import xyz.froud.jvisa.JVisaException;
    import xyz.froud.jvisa.JVisaInstrument;
    import xyz.froud.jvisa.JVisaResourceManager;
    
    public class JVisaExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (JVisaResourceManager rm = new JVisaResourceManager()) {
                JVisaInstrument instrument = rm.openInstrument("TCPIP::10.96.216.111::5025::SOCKET");
                String response = instrument.queryString("*IDN?");
                System.out.println(response);
    
                // instrument.write("INST OUT4");
                // instrument.write("VOLT 5");
                // instrument.write("CURR 0.1");
                // instrument.write("OUTP:SEL 1");
                // instrument.write("OUTP:GEN 1");
                // instrument.write("*RST");
    
                instrument.close();
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError | JVisaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the following lines of code before doing any read and write might fix your problem. It did for me.

```
instrument.setWriteTerminator("\r\n");
instrument.setReadTerminationCharacter('\n');
instrument.setReadTerminationCharacterEnabled(true);
```